# On Android 11 how do I start an Activity from a notification update WITHOUT actually tapping on the notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

My application (Xamarin.Android) runs as foreground service. The service hence has a permanent notification which I update. The app receives data from a bluetooth-enabled medical device. When comms arrive at my app, I update the notification with a counter (patient events in my case).

If I tap on the notification, my app launches so all good there, however, for certain incoming bluetooth packets, I need to actually start (or foreground) my activity, this needs to happen WITHOUT the user tapping on the notification. NB: I am only expecting this to work when device is unlocked, screen on, and with my app not in the foreground.

My code used to work just fine, so I suspect its googles changes to Android 10 and 11 that have stopped this working, but can it still be done?

My current code shown below

Many Thanks

Karen

```
/// <summary>
/// Assuming that the phone is not locked, and the screen is on, this brings the application to the foreground. It is used, for instance
/// where a patient event is inititiated while the user is viewing another app. The app is brought to the foreground by simply launching (or re-launching)
/// Main Activity
 /// </summary>
    public void BringToForeground()
    {
        var context = (Activity)MainApplication.ActivityContext;
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.KeyguardService);
        DisplayManager  displayManager  = (DisplayManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.DisplayService);

        var displayOn = false;
        foreach (var display in displayManager.GetDisplays())
        {
            if (display.State == DisplayState.On)
                displayOn = true;
        }

        if (!displayOn || keyguardManager.IsKeyguardLocked)
            return;

        //Check if we are already foregrounded, if so, return, nothing more to do
        var proteusAppProcess = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
        ActivityManager.GetMyMemoryState(proteusAppProcess);
        if (proteusAppProcess.Importance == Importance.Foreground)
            return;

        //Not foregrounded so re-launch intent - since this APP is SingleTop, this will replace any existing activity
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(StaticDefs.Com_Spacelabs_EclipsePatientApp_Android_SwitchScreenIntent);
        resultIntent.PutExtra(PageId.PageIdStringIdent, (int)PageId.RequestedPageId.PatientEventListScreen);
        resultIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NoHistory | ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
        context.StartActivity(resultIntent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, I think I can answer my own question - its due to the changes from Android 10 re who can launch foreground activities programatically.

To make the above code work, I needed to ask for the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission and then manually visit (or programmatically open) the Android settings page for my app and enable the 'Appear On Top' option.

After doing that, my activity starts like it used to.

Unfortunately, given that this is a medical app, likely used by elderly folks, expecting folks to manually re-config the app is not realistic, so I will put up with notification tap to launch activity. It seems that the SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission is required even though my app runs as a foreground service - foreground services being a way around the Android 9 background execution limits!

Karen